# Grafana Version Upgrade

Tags: centos, upgrade, grafana, rpm, yum

I installed grafana 8.3.4 enterprise version by mistake, while I wanted to install the OSS version 8.3.4. I tried installing and oss rpm package but it shows the following error :

```
Cannot install package grafana-8.3.4-1.x86_64. It is obsoleted by installed package grafana-enterprise-8.3.4-1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall enterprise version first:

> yum remove grafana-enterprise.x86_64

Only after that install a new one:

> yum install grafana-8.5.9-1.x86_64.rpm

Dont forget to update

> systemctl daemon-reload